# Compile Scala Project from GitHub on Mac OSX - Loading: net.java.games.input.OSXEnvironmentPlugin

Tags: java, macos, scala, opengl, lwjgl

I want to compile the following project on OSX:

https://github.com/TerranceN/Geometry-Wars-Clone-V2

Thanks to a cool guy on IRC, I already got this far:

```
sbt assembly
sbt run
```

When doing assembly there's a compiler error, through googling I found out that I have to change this line in build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.1"
```

to

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
```

Hence use another version of scala.

When running, it then was not able to see some native libs, so I created the folder "native_libs" in the root folder of the projects. After another run it copied some native lib-files (e.g. .so-files) into this folder and the app started for the first time!

Though it's having lots of errors and I think there's some OSX-specific problem here with LWJGL.
This is the full console log:

```
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    [info] Running com.awesome.Game
[info] native_lib/
[error] Dez 27, 2015 2:44:18 AM net.java.games.input.DefaultControllerEnvironment getControllers
[error] INFORMATION: Loading: net.java.games.input.OSXEnvironmentPlugin
[error] Dez 27, 2015 2:44:19 AM net.java.games.input.ControllerEnvironment log
[error] INFORMATION: Failed to enumerate device: Couldn't create plugin for device interface (3758097086)
[error]
[error]
[error] Dez 27, 2015 2:44:19 AM net.java.games.input.ControllerEnvironment log
[error] INFORMATION: Failed to enumerate device: Couldn't create plugin for device interface (3758097086)
[error]
[error]
[error] Dez 27, 2015 2:44:19 AM net.java.games.input.ControllerEnvironment log
[error] INFORMATION: Failed to enumerate device: Couldn't create plugin for device interface (3758097086)
[error]
[error]
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.SparkParticleSystem.<init>(SparkParticleSystem.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:25)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.SparkParticleSystem.<init>(SparkParticleSystem.scala:39)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:25)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.SparkParticleSystem.<init>(SparkParticleSystem.scala:37)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:25)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.SparkParticleSystem.<init>(SparkParticleSystem.scala:43)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:25)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.SparkParticleSystem.<init>(SparkParticleSystem.scala:44)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:25)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.SparkParticleSystem.<init>(SparkParticleSystem.scala:42)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:25)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.SparkParticleSystem.<init>(SparkParticleSystem.scala:48)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:25)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.SparkParticleSystem.<init>(SparkParticleSystem.scala:49)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:25)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.SparkParticleSystem.<init>(SparkParticleSystem.scala:47)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:25)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[info] 0
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.LineModel.<init>(LineModel.scala:18)
[error]     at com.awesome.Player$.<init>(Player.scala:121)
[error]     at com.awesome.Player$.<clinit>(Player.scala)
[error]     at com.awesome.Player.<init>(Player.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:50)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.LineModel.<init>(LineModel.scala:19)
[error]     at com.awesome.Player$.<init>(Player.scala:121)
[error]     at com.awesome.Player$.<clinit>(Player.scala)
[error]     at com.awesome.Player.<init>(Player.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:50)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.LineModel.<init>(LineModel.scala:17)
[error]     at com.awesome.Player$.<init>(Player.scala:121)
[error]     at com.awesome.Player$.<clinit>(Player.scala)
[error]     at com.awesome.Player.<init>(Player.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:50)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.LineModel.<init>(LineModel.scala:18)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment$.<init>(SnakeEnemy.scala:170)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment$.<clinit>(SnakeEnemy.scala)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment.<init>(SnakeEnemy.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment.<init>(SnakeEnemy.scala:9)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:51)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.LineModel.<init>(LineModel.scala:19)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment$.<init>(SnakeEnemy.scala:170)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment$.<clinit>(SnakeEnemy.scala)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment.<init>(SnakeEnemy.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment.<init>(SnakeEnemy.scala:9)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:51)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.LineModel.<init>(LineModel.scala:17)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment$.<init>(SnakeEnemy.scala:170)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment$.<clinit>(SnakeEnemy.scala)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment.<init>(SnakeEnemy.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.SnakeEnemySegment.<init>(SnakeEnemy.scala:9)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:51)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:61)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:62)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:60)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:66)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:67)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:65)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:71)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:72)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:70)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:76)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:77)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:75)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.Boundary.<init>(Boundary.scala:15)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:80)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.Boundary.<init>(Boundary.scala:16)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:80)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.Boundary.<init>(Boundary.scala:14)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:80)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.loadShaders(GBuffer.scala:107)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.setup(GBuffer.scala:48)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:85)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.loadShaders(GBuffer.scala:107)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.setup(GBuffer.scala:48)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:85)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.loadShaders(GBuffer.scala:107)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.setup(GBuffer.scala:48)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:85)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:92)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.VertexShader.<init>(Shader.scala:93)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.loadShaders(GBuffer.scala:108)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.setup(GBuffer.scala:48)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:85)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '130' is not supported
[error] ERROR: 0:9: 'int' : syntax error: syntax error
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.Shader$class.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:112)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.loadFromFile(Shader.scala:96)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.FragmentShader.<init>(Shader.scala:97)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.loadShaders(GBuffer.scala:108)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.setup(GBuffer.scala:48)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:85)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.Exception: Error creating shader: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
[error]
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:23)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.ShaderProgram.<init>(Shader.scala:12)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.loadShaders(GBuffer.scala:108)
[error]     at com.awesome.shaders.GBuffer.setup(GBuffer.scala:48)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Game.<init>(GS_Game.scala:85)
[error]     at com.awesome.GS_Init.init(GS_Init.scala:38)
[error]     at com.awesome.Game$GameRunner.run(Game.scala:47)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[info] draw fps: 0.9291309899452427
[info] OpenGL Error: 1282
[info] Invalid operation
[info] OpenGL Error: 1282
[info] Invalid operation
[info] OpenGL Error: 1282
[info] Invalid operation
[info] OpenGL Error: 1282
[info] Invalid operation
[info] OpenGL Error: 1282
[info] Invalid operation
[info] OpenGL Error: 1282
[info] Invalid operation
[info] OpenGL Error: 1282
[info] Invalid operation
[info] OpenGL Error: 1282
[info] Invalid operation
[info] OpenGL Error: 1282
[info] Invalid operation
```

Comment: I think this may be something particular to your OSX version or maybe something that is missing from it. I managed to get your project working on Linux after downloading [these files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-game-lib/files/Official%20Releases/LWJGL%202.9.0/) and then copying the relevant files (for me, Linux) to a folder called `native_lib` in the project root. I think the key error message here is `"version '130' is not supported"`. Googling for that may give you more leads.

Comment: Oh yeah, and I didn't use `sbt run` to run the projects; I've used `sbt assembly` to build it and then I used `java -jar -Djava.library.path="native_lib" target/scala-2.10/LWJGL\ Project-assembly-1.0.jar` to run the project, telling Java where the native libraries were located.

Comment: I tried exactly the same as you did on OSX (10.11.1) and it still gives me the error from above.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, but switching to core profile solve it. Here is the code (remember write it before creating a window)

```
glfwDefaultWindowHints();
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL11.GL_TRUE);
GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW.GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```